# Embedding category specific news feeds onto my site?

Tags: javascript, html, rss, feed

Hi is there a website or a way that i can embed category specific news feeds onto my website.

i am looking to feature news around gay politics, gay and lesbian cultures etc.

i cant find anything on the web that i can use just to get the news feeds on my site.

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

I basically have tried to find ways of embedding pinknews.co.uk and other sites which offer gay specific news but im not getting the help i need to do this. i would really appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

One thing i considered using was a javascript code to pull feeds from other sites but there are no feeds available for gay specific, could i create one just by typing in pinknews.co.uk somehow and embed there news content on my site?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
js_style = 1;
target = "_blank";
if (newsfeed){
    showNews(newsfeed, js_style);
} else {
    document.write("News feeds did not import correctly. Please contact the 24-7 pressrelease administrators");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google for "RSS".  You probably want to put RSS/Atom feeds on your site since that is the normal way for news feeds to work.